# JQuery validate + Gravity form conflict?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, jquery-validate, gravity-forms-plugin

As Gravity form doesn't have a client side validatation, I'm using JQuery Validate plugin. But the form is not submitting even if the form is properly filled.

Working :

- Filling all the fields before clicking on the submit button THEN click on the submit button -> The form is sending

No Working:

- Triggering the client side validation by clicking on the submit button with empty fields -> the validation is triggered -> fill the missing fields THEN click again on the submit button -> Strictly nothing happens.

So what I understand is that when the validation has been triggered once it will prevent the form sending EVEN if the form is properly filled later. Someone says the submitHandler is not needed ([Gravity Form is not submitting after client side validations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543935/gravity-form-is-not-submitting-after-client-side-validations)), I've also checked other posts without success.

I have then remove the submitHandler, but the form is still not submitting.

-Code with submitHandler :

```
if($(".contact-form").length){

    $(".contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
        input_5: {
            required: true,
        },
        input_2: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        input_3: {
            required: true,
        },
        input_4: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        input_5: 'Please enter your name',
        input_2: {
            required: 'Please enter your Email address',
            email: 'Please enter a valid Email address'
        },
        input_3: 'Please enter your Telephone Number',
        input_4: 'Please enter your Message',
    }, 
    submitHandler: function(form) {  
        if ($(form).valid())
           {
               form.submit(); 
           }
        return true;
    },

    });

};
```

-Code without submitHandler :

```
if($(".contact-form").length){

    $(".contact-form").validate({
        rules: {
            input_5: {
                required: true,
            },
            input_2: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            input_3: {
                required: true,
            },
            input_4: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            input_5: 'Please enter your name',
            input_2: {
                required: 'Please enter your Email address',
                email: 'Please enter a valid Email address'
            },
            input_3: 'Please enter your Telephone Number',
            input_4: 'Please enter your Message',
        }, 

    });

};
```

Both code are preventing the form to be sent.

Thank you.

//// Edit

I have the feeling that it's because all the s*** added to the submit button created by Gravity form :

```
<input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" class="gform_button button" value="Send" tabindex="5" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]){return false;}  window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]=true;  " onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]){return false;} window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]=true;  jQuery(&quot;#gform_1&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); }">
```

Because if I submit the form through the console it's working.

Here is the form generated by Gravity Form :

```
<div class="gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper contact-form_wrapper container_wrapper" id="gform_wrapper_1">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_1" class="contact-form container" action="/contact/" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="gform_heading">
            <h3 class="gform_title">Contact Form</h3>
            <span class="gform_description">Contact Form</span>
        </div>
        <div class="gform_body">
            <ul id="gform_fields_1" class="gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below">
                <li id="field_1_5" class="gfield form__single-input gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
                    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_5">Name<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text">
                        <input name="input_5" id="input_1_5" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="1" placeholder="Name*" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="field_1_2" class="gfield form__single-input gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
                    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_2">Email<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_email">
                        <input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="2" placeholder="Email*" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="field_1_3" class="gfield form__single-input gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
                    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_3">Telephone Number<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text">
                        <input name="input_3" id="input_1_3" type="text" value="" class="medium" tabindex="3" placeholder="Telephone Number*" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="field_1_4" class="gfield form__textarea gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
                    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_4">Message<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
                    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_textarea"><textarea name="input_4" id="input_1_4" class="textarea medium" tabindex="4" placeholder="Message*" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="field_1_6" class="gfield gform_validation_container field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_6">Phone</label>
                    <div class="ginput_container"><input name="input_6" id="input_1_6" type="text" value=""></div>
                    <div class="gfield_description">This field is for validation purposes and should be left unchanged.</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='gform_footer top_label'>

            <input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_1' class='gform_button button' value='Send' tabindex='5' onclick='if(window["gf_submitting_1"]){return false;}  window["gf_submitting_1"]=true;  ' onkeypress='if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window["gf_submitting_1"]){return false;} window["gf_submitting_1"]=true;  jQuery("#gform_1").trigger("submit",[true]); }' /> 
            <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='is_submit_1' value='1' />
            <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_submit' value='1' />

            <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_unique_id' value='' />
            <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='state_1' value='WyJbXSIsIjA3ZWZlNTFlNzIwYTFjNDVjNGEzMjExMmZjMTIxMDQ2Il0=' />
            <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_target_page_number_1' id='gform_target_page_number_1' value='0' />
            <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_source_page_number_1' id='gform_source_page_number_1' value='1' />
            <input type='hidden' name='gform_field_values' value='' />

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You do NOT need the `submitHandler` in your case:  It's already built into the plugin, and your logic is redundant.  The `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid, so putting `.valid()` within it makes no sense and it might throw something into a loop.  The `submitHandler` is only needed when you want to over-ride the default submit action, such as when using Ajax.

Comment: As far as answering your question, you're going to have to do a better job here.  Show the **relevant** HTML markup of the form and any other code that this depends upon.  We need to see enough code to make a demo.

Comment: Sparky thank you, I KNOW I don't need the submitHandler, it's clearly written in my post, and I know why (yes, it's clearly explain in the post I've linked to (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25550444/5658655), thus you are redundant). Gonna try to copy/past my whole html document, you might be able to help me. Thank you

Comment: If you already knew all that, then there was no need to even mention it or provide two versions of your code!  I was merely confirming something that appeared as if you were still very confused about.  Moving on, I'll see if I can spot your issue(s).

Comment: You don't need `if($(".contact-form").length)` since jQuery will automatically ignore any selectors that don't exist; but you probably already knew that.

Comment: Okay... this is the code exactly as you posted, and it's working fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/0ro26vqc/ ~ Sounds like you simply forgot to include the jQuery Validate plugin.  Otherwise, check your console for JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Sparky I'm going to explain you why I shown the 2 codes (with submit handler and without submit handler), but first, please stop to answer questions you haven't read entirely.

To be clear (even if it was already clear before) : The validation is working so copy/pasting the code I gave you in a JSFiddle won't help me (your fiddle doesn't send the form either), obviously it's working, and the validation is also working for me, the problem I have is that the form is not sending after the validation, You have totally removed the "Gravity Form/Wordpress" from the problem, thus your answer is not only incomplete, but you are answering to a question I haven't ask. Unless you install a local version of wordpress, install gravity form, create the same form with gravity, and test it, you won't be able to have the same result as me. NO console error and YES jQuery and jQuery validate plugin are linked.

So now, why I tried with the submit handler? As the implicit "submit" after the validation doesn't work, I was expecting that the explicit way (with the submit handler) would work. Unfortunatly it doesn't, and the reason I shown the 2 versions is to avoid people answering : "try with submit handler".

The first question is : Do someone has the same issue with JQuery validate AND Gravity Form AND Gravity Form AND Gravity form?

By the way I found a workaround, dirty workaround, redundant workaround but it's working in my case :

```
var $form = $(".contact-form");

$form.validate({
    rules: {
        input_5: {
            required: true,
        },
        input_2: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        input_3: {
            required: true,
        },
        input_4: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        input_5: 'Please enter your name',
        input_2: {
            required: 'Please enter your Email address',
            email: 'Please enter a valid Email address'
        },
        input_3: 'Please enter your Telephone Number',
        input_4: 'Please enter your Message',
    }, 
});


$form.on('click', function(){
    if($form.valid()){
        $form.submit();
    }
});
```

Thank you.